# Change C# Variable Name Dynamically in Loop

Tags: c#, mysql, dynamic

I am trying to enable and rename labels within a MySQLDataReader in C#. I am willing to do this outside of the loop if possible, but was wondering if there was a way to dynamically change the name of a variable. For example:

```
while (listNamesREAD.Read())
{
    int i = 0;
    //TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + fieldnames.GetString(0) + ", ";
    stringArray[i] = "List #" + listNamesREAD.GetString(0) + ": " + listNamesREAD.GetString(1);
    list1Label.Text = stringArray[i];
    i++;
}
```

If possible I would like the code to be able to change the name of list1Label each time it loops through. I am relatively new to Visual C# so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd0 = new MySqlCommand(listNames, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    listNamesREAD = cmd0.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        while (listNamesREAD.Read())
        {
            int i = 0;
            //TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + fieldnames.GetString(0) + ", ";
            stringArray[i] = "List #" + listNamesREAD.GetString(0) + ": " + listNamesREAD.GetString(1);
            list+i+Label.Text = stringArray[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
```

I am also willing to accomplish this outside of the DataReader if possible as well. Using a normal while loop because the array size is dynamic so I know exactly how many times to loop through -- it's just a matter of dynamically changing variable names.

Comment: ASP.NET - should've specified in the first post, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have an array of `TextBox`es you loop through. There is no way to accomplish this how you want to as C# is a statically typed language.

You can use the `Controls` property (which is a collection of all controls in the form) to accomplish what you need. You can access the controls by the indexer and the Controls' name:

```
  this.Controls["label1"].Text = yourText;
```

Comment: He doesn't need an array. He could accomplish his task with reflection or using `FindName` too.

Comment: I created an array of Labels & GridViews and then used this code in my loop -- is this an acceptable way of doing it?

`_Labels[i].Text = stringArray[i];`
`_Labels[i].Visible = true;`
`_GridViews[i].Visible = true;`

Answer (score 0):

do you want to change label name to accomplish which aim? 
do you have label named as: label1, label2, label3 and you'd like to change their text property?

you could do that by using linq.

Comment: I'd like to see how you would do that.

Comment: suppose you have an asp:panel and three labels [label1, label2, label3] in it. You can do: panel.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(lbl => lbl.Property == condition).ToList().ForEach(t => t.Text = "something");

Comment: mh, bad formatting ... i hope you can understsand that. it gives you an idea of what you can do by using linq syntax